# Scrape WebPage using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, cloudflare

I want to extract data from a [webpage](https://www.nccpl.com.pk/en/portfolio-investments/lipi-sector-wise-daily). To perform this task I am using selenium. The code to perform this task is as below.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time as t
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

date = pd.bdate_range('2021-08-05', '2021-08-05')

date = date[0].strftime('%d-%m-%y')

conv_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%y')

month = conv_date.strftime("%b")
year = conv_date.strftime("%Y")
day_name = conv_date.strftime("%A")
day = conv_date.strftime("%d")
day = day.lstrip("0")
month_full_name = conv_date.strftime("%B")
string = 'Select ' + day_name + ', ' + month + ' ' + day + ', ' + year

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.nccpl.com.pk/en/market-information/fipi-lipi/lipi-sector-wise-daily')
t.sleep(10)
picker = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'popupDatepicker')))
t.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', picker)
picker.click()
select_year = Select(wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="Change the year"]'))))
select_year.select_by_visible_text(year)
select_month = Select(
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="Change the month"]'))))
select_month.select_by_visible_text(month_full_name)
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="{}"]'.format(string)))).click()
search_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('search_btn')
search_button.click()

# addition
picker = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'popupDatepicker1')))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', picker)
picker.click()
select_year = Select(wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="Change the year"]'))))
select_year.select_by_visible_text(year)
select_month = Select(
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="Change the month"]'))))
select_month.select_by_visible_text(month_full_name)
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="{}"]'.format(string)))).click()
search_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('search_btn')
search_button.click()

htmlSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, 'html.parser')
data = pd.read_html(htmlSource)
```

At the point of picking up date despite adding sleep time web security stops and blocks the action. How can I bypass the security check and scrape the data?

**Edit**

See the error below:

[image]

Comment: _web security stops and blocks the action_: What error do you see?

Comment: see attached error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website is under Cloudflare protection, so normal chromedriver(nor geckodriver/Firefox) will not work here. You need to use something like `undetected-chromedriver` (install with `pip install undetected-chromedriver`).
The following code will give you the results you're looking for:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
import pandas as pd

browser = uc.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.nccpl.com.pk/en/portfolio-investments/lipi-sector-wise-daily'

start_date = '4/02/2021'
end_date = '5/08/2021'

browser.get(url)
picker = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'popupDatepicker')))
t.sleep(2)
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', picker)
picker.click()
t.sleep(3)
browser.execute_script(f'arguments[0].value = "{start_date}";', picker)
print('clicked the day!')
t.sleep(5)

picker = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'popupDatepicker1')))
t.sleep(2)
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', picker)
picker.click()
t.sleep(4)
browser.execute_script(f'arguments[0].value = "{end_date}";', picker)
print('clicked the second day!')
t.sleep(1)
search_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="search_btn"]/parent::div')
t.sleep(2)
search_button.click()
print('clicked search!')
t.sleep(10)
dfs = pd.read_html(browser.page_source)
dfs[0]
```

This returns a dataframe with 310 rows × 11 columns:

```
CLIENT TYPE SEC CODE    SECTOR NAME MARKET TYPE BUY VOLUME  BUY VALUE   SELL VOLUME SELL VALUE  NET VOLUME  NET VALUE   USD
0   BANKS / DFI S0036   Debt Market BNB 704000  3642335564  (808,511)   (4,399,617,995) (104,511)   (757,282,431)   (4,845,355)
1   BANKS / DFI S0005   Cement  FUT 3683000 323386465   (5,663,500) (573,804,520)   (1,980,500) (250,418,055)   (1,591,134)
2   BANKS / DFI S0007   Fertilizer  FUT 146000  43869760    (609,000)   (57,979,250)    (463,000)   (14,109,490)    (89,603)
3   BANKS / DFI S0008   Food and Personal Care Products FUT 22831500    890104750   (31,125,000)    (1,246,403,820) (8,293,500) (356,299,070)   (2,281,920)
4   BANKS / DFI S0019   Oil and Gas Exploration Companies   FUT 490000  51735820    (1,036,500) (102,697,770)   (546,500)   (50,961,950)    (323,286)
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Comment: I am still facing the same error (as seen in OP) upon clicking search.

Comment: The code above works for me, from multiple IPs. Are you sure you are running it as it is written above? Did you install undetected-chromedriver?

Comment: I've copied as is and ran the code, with another IP as well. Still facing the same issue. Can you recheck? yes, I did installed undetected-chromedriver.

Comment: I did recheck, and on multiple IPs as well. It works every time. Try restarting your system.

Comment: which version of undetected-chromedriver are you using?

Comment: undetected-chromedriver==3.1.5.post4

Comment: fixed now. I was using 3.0.4. It fixed after installing undetected-chromedriver==3.1.5.post4. Thank you for helping out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246739/discussion-between-lopez-and-platipus-on-fire-333).